# Unexpected behavior when combining increment operator with pointer dereferencing

Tags: c, pointers, increment

For a program that I'm currently working on, I am using code which includes this operation:

```
 *(a+++5) = 5; //increments a and adds 5 to it, then dereference that address
```

This behaves unexpectedly. The value 5 appears to be stored in the location (a+4), which is strange, because nothing is moving the pointer backwards. I found that the cause of this was the `a++`:

```
*(a++) = 5;
printf("%d\n" *(a-1)); //outputs 5
```

Using `++a` instead of `a++` makes a more logical result:

```
*(++a) = 5;
printf("%d\n" *a); //outputs 5
```

Could anybody explain to me why the code is behaving this way when i use `a++`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the behavior you should expect.

Let's say a points to the first element to an array, a = &array [0].

a++ increments a, but returns the previous value, so now a = &array [1], but the value that you get is &array [0].

a++ + 5 is therefore &array [5] and that is where you stored the value 5.

Since a is now equal to &array [1], the 5 was stored 4 after the new position of a.

Comment: Oops. I've overlooked something crucial.

Answer (score 2):

That is the expected result because you are using the post-increment operator which increments only after the sequence point ( in this case, the end of the statement ) is reached.

```
*(a+++5) = 5;
```

is same as

```
*(a + 5) = 5;
a++;
```

So, `*( a + 5 ) = 5` stores the value 5 at `a[5]`. But after `a++`, `a` will now actually point to `a[1]`, so `a[4]` will have the value which was earlier stored in `a[5]`, so that explains the behavior you were getting.

Lets look at the C Standard

**6.5.2.4**

> 2 The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand.
>   As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
>   is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it).

Let's look at an example

```
int x = 5 , y;
y = x++;
printf("y : %d  ,  x : %d\n",y,x);
y = ++x;
printf("y : %d  ,  x : %d\n",y,x);
```

And the output you get is

```
y : 5  ,  x : 6
y : 7  ,  x : 7
```

So, as stated in the standard, the value of `y` after `y = x++;` will be the original value of `x`, and as an aftereffect, the value of `x` is incremented.

The first code ( `y = x++;` ) first assigns the value of `x` ( 5 ) to `y` and then increments `x`. That is the postfix increment operator.

The second one ( `y = ++x;` ) first increments `x` to 7, and then assigns it to `y`. That is how the pre-increment operator works.

Answer (score 0):

Example of operations' order:

```
b = 5 + a++; // same as:   b = 5 + a;   a = a + 1;

b = 5 + ++a; // same as:   a = a + 1;   b = 5 + a;
```

Why?... because:

```
a++ // adds after the line command.

++a // adds before th line command.
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

*(a+++5)=5 does this

```
 *(a+5)=5 //so a[5]=5
 a=a+1 //that gives a[4]=5
```

likewise *(a++)=5 :

```
 *a=5 //so a[0]=5
 a=a+1//incrementation on address => a[-1]=5
 //*a=content at address "a" and a is an address that you incremented
```

Answer (score 0):

tokens are extracted as longest string first.
and trailing `++` is done after the fact,

therefore, the statement (which you should be using parens to clarify what you really want) becomes: `*(a+5) = 5; a++;`